# GitLab CI passa o teste mesmo com erro

Tags: python, flask, gitlab, integração-contínua

Estou trabalhando com python/flask em uma aplicação. Quero testar o CI do GitLab, então fiz um teste que gera um erro, só para ver como seria o funcionamento. Mas, acontece que o o CI passa o Job mesmo dando erro. Poderiam me ajudar? [image: Essa é a mensagem do CI]

[image: Esse é o .gitlab-ci.yml]
[image: Esse é o comando que criei pra rodar todos os tests da pasta 'tests']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando o comando do .gitlab-ci.yml. O "python3 manager.py test", eu mudei para "python3 -m unittest discover -s tests/". Sendo que "tests/" é a minha pasta onde se encontram os testes.